# During "NPM I" facing error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'v8::String::Utf8Value'

Tags: npm, error-handling, utf-8, constructor, npm-install

I am trying to run `npm i`, but it gives me the error:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'v8::String::Utf8Value'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem today when I picked up a project that was working 5 months ago.

The whole game is to keep your dependencies updated in `package.json`.

The problem happens when there is some version mismatch in your components because something has updated behind the scenes. I suggest you go one by one and start installing latest stable versions of all dependencies. I've just been able to solve the problem with my angular project.

Every time you install a latest version of the dependency, it tells you what else it needs and you go install that. You'll realise that you don't have to install everything and half of it gets updated automatically.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this issue, I just updated the npm version I was using to `v10.16.0`, then launched the `npm install` command afterwards; and the error was no more.